# What is the obvious way of making a simple async socket chat server in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am getting my mind around asyncio and I would like to write a simple socked-based chat server. I have been looking around to understand what is the best way to approach this task.

Unfortunately, it appears that there is no ***"obvious way to do it"***. I find myself unable to decide, for example, whether to use `@asincio.coroutine` or `async def`, whether to use `asyncio.Protocol` of `.start_server` or `.asynchat`. or something else?
Does it actually make any difference in practice?

Could you please help enlight me on this?

Comment: Walkthrough from David Beazley here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzfHjytDceU

Comment: @BradSolomon It's a fantastic lecture, but it's more useful for understanding how asyncio is built than how to use it effectively. In fact, David professes his **confusion** at various aspects of asyncio throughout the talk, which later culminated in the creation of [curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find myself unable to decide, for example, whether to use `@asincio.coroutine` or `async def`

Use `async def`. You need `@asyncio.coroutine` only if you want to support pre-3.5 Python, or perhaps if you are writing very specialized implementations of low-level coroutines.

> whether to use `asyncio.Protocol` of `.start_server`

Go with `start_server`. The stream-based APIs expose coroutines to the API user and are how asyncio is meant to be interfaced with by the majority of application code. Understanding transports and protocols is important if you are digging into the details, or if you are writing an asyncio-based library that implements a whole protocol.

> or `.asynchat`

According to its own documentation, asynchat is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asynchat.html).

Comment: can you suggest any good document on "pythonic way of dealing with async stuff"?

Comment: @alec_djinn I can point you to a [reading list](https://morestina.net/blog/1213/asyncio-reading-list) of articles useful to me while learning asyncio. Disclaimer: I compiled the list.